# Facebook Graph API /debug_token not returning expires_at

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am using the PHP SDK and trying to get a user's access token's expiration date.  According to Facebook docs

```
GET /debug_token?
     input_token={input-token}&
     access_token={access-token}
```

Should return

```
{
    "data": {
        "app_id": 138483919580948, 
        "application": "Social Cafe", 
        "expires_at": 1352419328, 
        "is_valid": true, 
        "issued_at": 1347235328, 
        "metadata": {
            "sso": "iphone-safari"
        }, 
        "scopes": [
            "email", 
            "publish_actions"
        ], 
        "user_id": 1207059
    }
}
```

However when I run

```
$access_token_debug = $facebook->api('/debug_token', 'GET', array(
    'input_token' => 'USER_TOKEN',
    'access_token' => 'APP_TOKEN'
));
```

I get this returned:

```
Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [app_id] => 3.31449226977465E+14
                    [is_valid] => 1
                )

        )
```

I am really only interested in the `expires_at` parameter.  Is there something else I should be doing?  Possibly a setting I forgot to enable?

Answer (score 0):

Its may be that for the provided input token you have already permission of manage_pages.
If a long lived access exchanged for the manages_pages permission it has no expiry date.